# run a python file on a server

Tags: bash, ftp

I am trying to run a Python file which is on a server.
I wrote the bash script like this :

```
    #!/bin/bash -x
    ftp -in 100.200.100.200 << SCRIPTEND
    user user password
    binary
    cd dem
    ls # Works
    python hello.py #Tried This doesnt work
    ./hello.py      #Tried This doesnt work
    /usr/bin/python hello.py #Tried This doesnt work
    /usr/bin/python /full/path/hello.py #Tried This doesnt work
    mkdir abc   #Works
    SCRIPTEND
```

I Tried by giving `chown +x` to **hello.py** then tried with `chown u+rx` 
What is my stupid mistake please tell me.

Errors I get when I run the script:

```
?Invalid command
?Invalid command
```

Comment: Just to make sure, python is installed somewhere on the server, yes?

Comment: What are the error messages you are getting

Comment: `ftp` is for file transfer. You need to use `ssh`, `telnet`, ...

Comment: Yes Python is there. :D

Comment: To second @falsetru. You cannot run commands via `ftp`. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @falsetru I would prefer ssh for this anytime but I have a compulsion to do this using ftp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` is ftp command which is not a system ls command. You can use only the following commands in ftp.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ftp.htm

In your case you need to use SSH or TELNET to execute the script.

```
[root@server1 tmp]# cat hello.py
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Hello"

[root@server1 tmp]# ./hello.py
Hello


[root@server2 ~]# ssh -t server1 << EOF
> /tmp/hello.py
> EOF
Hello
```